# Recurrence relations in Maple using Matrices

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, recurrence, maple

So like the title suggests I'm doing a Project in maple that involves using recurrence.

As an ex. suppose we have an **3x3** matrix called **A** and we multiply it by a **3x1**(**B**) and then add it to a **3x1**(**C**) and the resulting matrix is used as the new **B** and we do the same operation over. How would I go about doing this in maple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a [procedure](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=procedure):

```
recurrence := proc(A,b,c,n)
    ## A is a k x k matrix
    ## b is a 1 x k vector
    ## c is a 1 x k vector
    ## n is the number of iterations

    local btemp, i;

    btemp := b;

    for i to n do
        btemp := A.btemp+c;
    end do;
end proc:
```

Example of use:

```
A:= <<1,4,7>|<2,5,8>|<3,6,9>>;
b:=<1/10,1/10,1/10>;
c:=<-1,2,-2>;
seq(recurrence(A,b,c,n),n = 1..3);  ## Output the recurrence for 1,2 and 3 iterations
```